# Display if subarrays > 3 - PHP

Tags: php

So I have a tv show website and I created custom lists where you can add whatever tv shows you want.

There is one table called lists (with user_id, list_title) and another table called show_lists which contains (list_id, show_id).

So my PHP is there:

```
     <?php
   $findlistsq = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM show_lists, shows, lists 
    WHERE lists.user_id = :user_id AND 
    lists.list_id = show_lists.list_id AND
    shows.id = show_lists.show_id');
   $findlistsq->execute(array(':user_id' => 2));
   $listscount = $findlistsq->rowCount();
         echo $listscount;
   $list = array();
   while ($listarray = $findlistsq->fetch()) {

    $list[$listarray['list_title']][$listarray['name']] = $listarray;

   }
   ?>    


   <?php
   foreach ($list as $key => $show) {
        echo $key; //echo title of list
       foreach ($show as $key => $value) {


        echo $value['name'];  //echo tv shows
     ;
    }
   }
   ?>
```

Basically, I create an array to join a list to its tv shows, display the title of the list and whatever it contains and so on. My question is: I want to display the list only if there is more than 3 shows (at least 3 different $value).

Can anybody tell me how I could do that ? Thanks!!

Edit: Also, there is slight chance that I might have overcomplicated this. Let me know if I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation of your data is not great, but you could try doing this in the `SELECT` statement, this will be faster than messing with arrays.

```
$findlistsq = $conn->prepare('SELECT * 
  FROM show_lists, shows, lists 
  WHERE 
    lists.user_id = :user_id AND 
    lists.list_id = show_lists.list_id AND
    shows.id = show_lists.show_id AND 
    COUNT(DISTINCT shows.id) > 3');
```

This will count the `DISTINCT` (unique) show ids and only return you a data set if there are more than 3 `DISTINCT` show ids.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into is_array() and count()

```
$list = array('show1','show2','show3');

if(is_array($list)){
    if(count($list) > 3){
        //more than 3 shows found, execute code!
    }
}
```

Comment: they specified "at least 3 *different* $value". not sure if they really need to check that, but just in case, you can use `array_unique` to strip out duplicate values before using `count`

Comment: Why `is_array()`? $list is already initialized as an array (both in OP's question and in your code)

Comment: Force of habit. I work in a dev environment where ALL errors always show so I've been screwed up by trying to use count() without checking if it is an array/object. It is exponentially frustrating when trying to debug an AJAX call and something minor throws a Notice message. My production site has all errors turned off so I know that if it can survive dev without tripping anything up then my visitors will always have a smooth experience.